# curl upload file using HTTP GET to Page

Tags: php, http, rest, curl, get

How do I send data in a file using HTTP GET To a php script ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you mean file uploads: You don't. The GET method doesn't support file uploads. Also, the method has a length limit between 2-4 kilobytes (depending on browser and server) so it's not suitable for most files anyway.

You would have to either fetch the file's contents and send them as an explicit GET parameter (bearing in mind the length limit), or use POST.

Answer (score 1):

You could use GET to upload files, but this method im going to describe is a more covert way to do it.

In fact this method is used by a tool called SQLNINJA so Ill just ref you to its MAN page's description.

http://sqlninja.sourceforge.net/sqlninja-howto.html#ss2.6